# Array of quaternions in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, quaternions

I want to create an array (or a vector) of Quaternions in MATLAB.

I am doing an interpolation and I want to store the values of the interpolated quaternions in an array.

The problem is how can I define this array so that every result of my for loop will be stored in an data structure of quaternion?

I use the robotics toolbox for the Quaternions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab a quaternion is a 1x4 vector, thus an array of quaternions is a nx4 matrix.

```
%create:
x=zeros(n,4);
%access:
x(2,:)
```